# wrap submenus in separate divs for bootstrap carousel

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a dynamic submenu for my wordpress site, I used walker nav menu for the submenu to show title, image and description. Everything is working perfectly except I want to add a bootstrap carousel and I can't seem to get my way around wrapping the lists inside sub menu. This is my current structure.

```
<ul>
  <li>link 1</li>
  <li>link 2</li>
  <li>link 3
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>Sub-menu-item 1</li>
        <li>Sub-menu-item 2</li>
        <li>Sub-menu-item 3</li>
        <li>SUb-menu-item 4</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What is want to achieve is this:

```
<ul>
  <li>link 1</li>
  <li>link 2</li>
  <li>link 3
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <div class="carousel-class-here">
         <li>Sub-menu-item 1</li>
         <li>Sub-menu-item 2</li>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-class-here">
         <li>Sub-menu-item 3</li>
         <li>Sub-menu-item 4</li>
        </div>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you generating this with PHP? What exactly is your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it with jquery this way

```
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
      var items = $('.sub-menu > li');
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i += 2) {
        items.slice(i, i + 2).wrapAll('<div class="carousel-class-here"></div>');
      };
    });
    </script>
```

Checkout my [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aguilar1181/w52bhhtz/)